# Accessing object properties from a treenode that's associated with it?

Tags: c#, treenode

Hallo, 
I have read [Easy object binding to Treeview Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880930/easy-object-binding-to-treeview-node),
but still have unanswered question.

if an object is associated with treenode tag property, how to access that object members/properties from that treenode ?

```
node1 = new TreeNode();
node1.tag = object1;
//ex:if object1 has public property valueA
//How to access valueA  from node1 ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can cast it back to the object1 type...

```
var valueA = ((object1Type)node1.tag).valueA;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass c = treeNode.Tag as MyClass;
theValue = c.TheProperty;
```

If you don't know the type of the object in question, then you can use System.Reflection:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = treeNode.Tag.GetType().GetProperty("SomeName");
theValue = pi.GetValue(treeNode.Tag, null);
```

Finally, if you want to know the names of the properties, again System.Reflection to the rescue:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] pis = treeNode.Tage.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var pi in pis) {
  theName = pi.Name;
}
```